# Bug in NDB Transaction?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, transactions, app-engine-ndb

I've been using a code snippet similar to what I copied below for a couple years.

The basic is idea is that a `Person` can be married, and when they are married, I create a 'Marriage' entity.  A person can only be married once, so I have a boolean to indicate whether the person is married (`Person.married`).  When a person becomes married, I update the `Person` and create the `Marriage` entity in a transaction like this:

```
@ndb.transactional(xg=True)
def update_person(pid):
    person = Person.get_by_id(pid)
    if person.married:
        raise RuntimeError("This person is already married.")
    else:
        marriage = Marriage(person=person)
        person.married = True
        ndb.put_multi([person, marriage])
```

This is the only place in my code where a `Marriage` entity is created. All updates to `Person` entities are done in transactions.

Somehow, I now have a Person entity who is married twice (part of two Marriage entities)!  This is the first time it has happened in years, but it is disconcerting that this could happen.

Is there a bug in my code?  If not, any idea how this happened?

Comment: Probably not the case, but I thought I'd mentioned it - I managed to find similar inconsistencies in my entities. Eventually I figured out it was because I also fiddled with the entities from admin console - changes from the console aren't transaction-protected (and also don't update the ndb caches)

Comment: @DanCornilescu, yeah, I've stopped editing entities in the console and now only do so using remote api shell.  My reason was because console doesn't update memcache but this is another good reason.

Answer (score 1):

were both marriages created at the same time?

I've had weird stale cache issues, maybe make this change: `use_cache=False, use_memcache=False`

So this:

```
person = Person.get_by_id(pid, use_cache=False, use_memcache=False)
```

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/cache

Also, do all of your functions that edit `Person` happen in transactions? Like somewhere else in your code do you have a function like this:

```
def update_person_email(pid, email):
    person = Person.get_by_id(pid)
    person.email = email
    person.put()
```

If so, then maybe the sequence of events was:

- `update_person_email` gets `Person` A
- your `update_person` gets and puts `Person` A
- `update_person_email` puts `Person` A (overwriting `married` to be false again)

Comment: Yes, good question, all updates to `Person` entities happen in transactions.  The two marriages were created 40 minutes apart so probably not a cache issue.

Comment: In general the logic should work. The problem is then that `Person.married` got wiped out somewhere else.  Do you have another function that 'unmarries' someone? The only other thing that would make your logic better would be checking for the existence of a `Marriage` object instead of using `Person.married`. You could do this by making `Person` an ancestor of `Marriage`. Another option is have your `Marriage` use  `Person`'s id as it's id: `marriage = Marriage(key=ndb.Key(Marriage, pid),person=person)`. Then you'd be able to fetch it inside your transaction.

Comment: I don't have an unmarry function (my app is something different but I thought this was a nice simple example).  Your code suggestions are good ones, but it seems that I shouldn't need them.  I wish I could understand how this happened...